# Check if LogCat is already running

Tags: java, android, logcat

When i Start the application I run a logcat Process for saving logging data on the android device.

e.g somethin like this.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
         File logDir = new File("pathToLogFile");
         process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + logFile.getAbsolutePath() + " " + Setting.getInstance().logKey + ":V *:E");
    }
```

This works fine. Exept if the activity is started more than once: Multiple lines for each event are created in the log file

```
    Log.d("some log entry");
```

creates these entries in the logfile

```
    01-09 16:04:15.942 24768 24883 D IDDT    : some log entry
    01-09 16:04:15.942 24768 24883 D IDDT    : some log entry
    01-09 16:04:15.942 24768 24883 D IDDT    : some log entry
    01-09 16:04:15.942 24768 24883 D IDDT    : some log entry
```

My educational guess is, that `logcat -f` is still running when the activity is recreated. That means every `logcat -f` process creates a single log entry line for every event. How I fix this issue? Is there a way to check if the `logcat -f`command is already running?

Comment: Why do not use a 3rd library for Loggin? Or just create a Class and implement a static "writeLogToFile()" method that is accessible from everywhere?

Comment: Because I thought that logcat provide everything that I need exept storing the logs in a file. What for a 3rd party lib do you recommend?